# Android passing ArrayList<Model> to Fragment from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-tabs

Hi I want to send the data `ArrayList<Division>` to Fragment class `ListContentFragment`.

In `MainActivity` I am making a network call to get the data(`JSON`) and then parsing it to create `ArrayList<Division>`, now i want to populate the list view with the data i received (now in `ArrayList<Division>`)

MainActivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Adding Toolbar to Main screen
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        // Create Navigation drawer and inlfate layout
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        // Adding menu icon to Toolbar
        ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            VectorDrawableCompat indicator
                    = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu, getTheme());
            indicator.setTint(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.white,getTheme()));
            supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(indicator);
            supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        // Set behavior of Navigation drawer
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // Set item in checked state
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);

                        // TODO: handle navigation
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked: " + menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Closing drawer on item click
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        // Adding Floating Action Button to bottom right of main view
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "Hello Snackbar!",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Network request test with volley
        NetworkRequests networkRequest = new NetworkRequests(this);
        networkRequest.fetchDummyData();
        divisionList = networkRequest.getDivisions();
    }

    // Add Fragments to Tabs
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ListContentFragment(), "List");
        adapter.addFragment(new TileContentFragment(), "Tile");
        adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "Card");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Fragment (currently its hard coded, want to populate with the ArrayList)

```
public class ListContentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return recyclerView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView avator;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false));
            avator = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_avatar);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_desc);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter to display recycler view.
     */
    public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        // Set numbers of List in RecyclerView.
        private static final int LENGTH = 18;

        private final String[] mPlaces;
        private final String[] mPlaceDesc;
        private final Drawable[] mPlaceAvators;

        public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            mPlaces = resources.getStringArray(R.array.places);
            mPlaceDesc = resources.getStringArray(R.array.place_desc);
            TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.place_avator);
            mPlaceAvators = new Drawable[a.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < mPlaceAvators.length; i++) {
                mPlaceAvators[i] = a.getDrawable(i);
            }
            a.recycle();
        }
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.avator.setImageDrawable(mPlaceAvators[position % mPlaceAvators.length]);
            holder.name.setText(mPlaces[position % mPlaces.length]);
            holder.description.setText(mPlaceDesc[position % mPlaceDesc.length]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return LENGTH;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass an ArrayList to your fragment, then you need to make sure the Model class is implements Parcelable.
Here i can show an example.

```
public class ObjectName implements Parcelable {


    public ObjectName(Parcel in) {
        super();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ObjectName> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ObjectName>() {
        public ObjectName createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ObjectName(in);
        }

        public ObjectName[] newArray(int size) {

            return new ObjectName[size];
        }

    };

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Value1 = in.readInt();
        Value2 = in.readInt();
        Value3 = in.readInt();

    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(Value1);
        dest.writeInt(Value2);
        dest.writeInt(Value3);
    }
}
```

then you can add `ArrayList<ObjectName>` to a Bundle object.

```
ArrayList<ObjectName> arraylist = new Arraylist<ObjectName>();  
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arraylist", arraylist);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

After this you can get back this data by using,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
ArrayList<ObjectName> arraylist  = extras.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
```

At last you can show list with these data in fragment. Hope this will help to get your expected answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex.. I will implement this.

Answer (score 4):

I was also stuck with the same problem .
You can try this.
Intead of sending the arraylist as bundle to fragment.Make the arraylist to be passed,as public and static in the activity.

```
public static Arraylist<Division> arraylist;
```

Then after parsing and adding the data in the arraylist make the call to the fragment.In the fragment you can the use the arraylist as:

```
ArrayList<Division> list=MainActivity.arraylist;
```

Comment: What are the demerits ?

Comment: Memory leaks are the main cause for making static variable or objects

Comment: If the Activity is not destroyed then how memory leak will occur? Can you explain?