# Implementing a Favorite List in Android using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I want to create a favorite list using `SharedPreferences` and I am trying to save some **lists** in it. There is an option for saving a **String Set** in `SharedPreferences` but the **set** does not keep **Duplicate** values.
I want to store a list of **duplicates** with `SharedPreferences`. What should I do?

Also how can I convert an `ArrayList<String>` to `HashSet<String>` ?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: convert `list` to `set` : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-list-to-set-arraylist-to-hastset/

Comment: also if `SharedPreferences` cannot store `list`..try another way to store your variable..is it an activity to fragment..or fragment to activity?

Comment: i suggest u to use `intent` to store the variable..then when u change the page..u can get it from `intent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. java convert `list` to `set`:

http://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-list-to-set-arraylist-to-hastset

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

2. I suggest using `intent` and `bundle` to store the list

**Activity to Activity**

[Pass list of objects from one activity to other activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092612/pass-list-of-objects-from-one-activity-to-other-activity-in-android)

Store data:

```
// activity a
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("test", arrayList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve data:

```
// activity b
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Object test = bundle.getParcelable("test");
```

**Activity to Fragment**

[Android passing ArrayList<Model> to Fragment from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867847/android-passing-arraylistmodel-to-fragment-from-activity)

Store data:

```
// activity a
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("test", arraylist);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Retrieve data:

```
// fragment a
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
List<String> arraylist = extras.getParcelableArrayList("test");
```